# c++ faster if else statements

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement

I am a new c++ user and wrote a code that works along with other functions. I needed to make a modification to the code with if & else if statements, which resulted in elapsing the entire code 4.6333 mins, compared to 0.61 mins before modification (note these durations are for entire code not for the example I pasted below).

Here below if the "only" the modified part as an example (which can be run in c++ individually).

Anyone has any suggestion to get this code faster?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static const double InflVecVals001[9] = { 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 700.0, 800.0, 900.0 };
    int FloorMnodeTagscol1[6] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }; int FloorMnodeTagscol6[6] = { 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66 };
    int FloorMnodeTagscol2[6] = { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 }; int FloorMnodeTagscol7[6] = { 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76 };
    int FloorMnodeTagscol3[6] = { 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36 }; int FloorMnodeTagscol8[6] = { 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86 };
    int FloorMnodeTagscol4[6] = { 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46 }; int FloorMnodeTagscol9[6] = { 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96 };
    int FloorMnodeTagscol5[6] = { 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56 };

    int tagNode = 91;
    double fact;

    if ((tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol1[0]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol1[1]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol1[2]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol1[3]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol1[4]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol1[5]))
    {
        fact = InflVecVals001[0];
    }
    else if ((tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol2[0]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol2[1]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol2[2]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol2[3]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol2[4]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol2[5]))
    {
        fact = InflVecVals001[1];
    }
    else if ((tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol3[0]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol3[1]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol3[2]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol3[3]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol3[4]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol3[5]))
    {
        fact = InflVecVals001[2];
    }
    else if ((tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol4[0]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol4[1]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol4[2]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol4[3]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol4[4]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol4[5]))
    {
        fact = InflVecVals001[3];
    }
    else if ((tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol5[0]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol5[1]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol5[2]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol5[3]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol5[4]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol5[5]))
    {
        fact = InflVecVals001[4];
    }
    else if ((tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol6[0]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol6[1]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol6[2]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol6[3]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol6[4]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol6[5]))
    {
        fact = InflVecVals001[5];
    }
    else if ((tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol7[0]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol7[1]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol7[2]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol7[3]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol7[4]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol7[5]))
    {
        fact = InflVecVals001[6];
    }
    else if ((tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol8[0]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol8[1]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol8[2]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol8[3]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol8[4]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol8[5]))
    {
        fact = InflVecVals001[7];
    }
    else if ((tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol9[0]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol9[1]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol9[2]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol9[3]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol9[4]) || (tagNode == FloorMnodeTagscol9[5]))
    {
        fact = InflVecVals001[8];
    }
    else
    {
        fact = 1.0;
    }
    //cout << "\n tagnode:" << tagNode << endl;
    //cout << "\n factor:" << fact << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up "2D arrays". I think you should be more worried about the looks and maintenance here.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this code could take several minutes to complete (it doesn't even have a single loop). Is this your real code?

Comment: What was the modification?

Comment: Did you measure the time with the cin.get() statement at the end?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Might be running on a toaster.

Comment: "note these durations are for entire code not for the example I pasted below" Are all the set of values (like the `FloorMnodeTagscolX` arrays in your example, but for the whole code) disjunct or can a value appear in more than one such a set)?

Comment: Are all the sets 6 elements short or do you have longer sets?

Comment: Are any of the `[minVal, maxVal]` ranges (as defined for each of the sets) overlapping? (because if they are not, you can go "first find what set the tagNode likely belong and then confirm if is or it is not in there")

Comment: I have no idea why I got -4 votes!!!!! Some of you ask stupid questions; I double noted that the example I m giving is not the code that runs 4.6333 seconds. Original code is probably about 20000 lines. Thank you @Adrian Colomitchi :))

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi  Yes FloorMnodeTagscolX are all 1x6 vectors

Comment: @LogicStuff: Would 2D array be faster than if-else or mapping (see jared42's answer below) methods? You have any example of it?

Answer (score 0):

With your sample code, you may simply to

```
if ((tagNode - 1) % 10 < 6 && 11 <= tagNode && tagNode <= 96) {
    fact = (tagNode / 10) * 100.;
} else {
    fact = 1.;
}
```

But assuming values are not simple range as in your example, and that you have to do the mapping several time, you may do something like:

```
static const std::map<int, double> m = {
    { 11, 100.}, {12, 100.}, {13, 100.}, {14, 100.}, {15, 100.}, {16, 100.},
    { 21, 200.}, {22, 200.}, {23, 200.}, {24, 200.}, {25, 200.}, {26, 200.},
    { 31, 300.}, {32, 300.}, {33, 300.}, {34, 300.}, {35, 300.}, {36, 300.},
    { 41, 400.}, {42, 400.}, {43, 400.}, {44, 400.}, {45, 400.}, {46, 400.},
    { 51, 500.}, {52, 500.}, {53, 500.}, {54, 500.}, {55, 500.}, {56, 500.},
    { 61, 600.}, {62, 600.}, {63, 600.}, {64, 600.}, {65, 600.}, {66, 600.},
    { 71, 700.}, {72, 700.}, {73, 700.}, {74, 700.}, {75, 700.}, {76, 700.},
    { 81, 800.}, {82, 800.}, {83, 800.}, {84, 800.}, {85, 800.}, {86, 800.},
    { 91, 900.}, {92, 900.}, {93, 900.}, {94, 900.}, {95, 900.}, {96, 900.}
};

auto it = m.find(tagNode);

fact = ((it != m.end()) ? it-> second : 1.);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/pxdX7w)

Which have

- `N log N` for map construction (done once).
- `log(N)` complexity for the search.

instead of your linear search.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Jarod42. The InflVecVals001[9] vector is actually an arbitrary 1x9 vector and I gave those values to just distinguish indexes and values. Can you explain what exactly your codes is doing in this second part (static const map<int, double> m = {... ) please?

Comment: Can I just copy/paste your code into VS and run? 
I get some error messages, e.g., "map is not a template"
Need #include <map> ? 
"Error: expected an identifier"; "Error: expected declaration" after or before commas ad curly brackets....

Comment: @IsmailBahadirKuzucu: Typo fixed, and example added. Yes `#include <map>` is required.

Comment: `static const map<int, double> m = {..};` initializes a map structure. You may look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map for a description of that associative container.

Comment: This is Ok if any pair of the individual sets of values has an empty intersection - so that a simple mapping `tagNode->fact` is non-ambiguous. If at least one of the `tagNode` values is mapped to two or more different `fact` values, the implicit rules of disambiguation in the original code (chained `if-elseif`s) is "the winner is the first set examined for the presence of `tagValue` to answer in the positive". If this would be the case, the above solution is not going to work (because it establishes the rule of "the last `fact` added to the map for a `tagValue` key wins").

Comment: @Jarod42:  Thank you, I like the mapping method, which reduced the lines, but performance has been affected adversely; interestingly it took 19mins compared to 4.6mins with "if-else" statements. Any ideas?

Comment: @IsmailBahadirKuzucu: Firstly, you may remove the conflicted pairs from the map creation. Secondly, from the given initialization, it is the first one which wins.

Comment: @IsmailBahadirKuzucu: You don't show how you use it. As I said, the map construction takes more time than your snippet, so if you build it each time, it is longer.

Comment: @Jarod42:   Yes it is being built in every time step, currently 6000 times. Yeah it was good to learn this mapping method, if not any other method could do the job faster, I better stick with the snippet method then?